# Linux: script won't start at boot

Tags: linux, boot

I've a python server wich I want to start at boot. This server is listening to a specific port for input.

I've created a new cronjob `crontab -e`

`@reboot /path/to/script`

Put the script in `/etc/init.d` and created sybmbolic links to it.

The script runs fine when I use `/path/to/script` the script runs fine.

Comment: Is there any subprocess in your python script, like running a shell command ?

Comment: It connects to a mysql db

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to copy-paste an existing init.d file and replace the all the junk with ways to start your script? (hell, you only really need the 'start' and 'stop' option in an init.d script). That way you can set it to boot up automagically and forget about it.

Comment: Is it connects with python lib or executable ? I think something is different in your environment cron -> interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Put inside your init script

```
source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile
```

I guess the environment is different in `crontab` and in interactive session.